# Polymer - How to get the component which contains my component in its shadow-DOM?

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom

If my component has explicitly been placed in another shadow-dom component, how to get this component?

For instance:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic way to get the parent element when you are placed in their shadow DOM. I did not add any error checking, but if you know you are in their shadow then this works just fine.

```js
class OuterEl extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
          super();
          var root = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
          root.innerHTML = "<inner-el></inner-el>";
        }
      }

      class InnerEl extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
          super();
          var root = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
          root.innerHTML = `<button>Click</button><hr/><output></output>`;
          this.button = root.querySelector('button');
          this.output = root.querySelector('output');
          this.button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let parentSrc = this.getRootNode();
            this.output.textContent = parentSrc.host.outerHTML;
          })
        }
      }

      customElements.define('outer-el', OuterEl);
      customElements.define('inner-el', InnerEl);
    </script>
```

```html
<outer-el></outer-el>
```

The magic is found in this call:

`this.getRootNode().host`

This will be the element that has the shadow DOM in which your component lives.